# Apache Camel: Risk with Bean component not able to link the bean method at compile time

Tags: java, apache-camel

Camel's bean component takes the method name as a string, which is used at runtime to invoke that method.

```
from("direct:start")
.bean(contactDao, "getContactById")
```

But, this is bad when compared to Java which links the methods at compile time itself and so any errors are detected at compile time itself.

In camel, any error with the bean method invocation will not be caught until that flow is triggered at runtime.

Are there any safety measures to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `org.apache.camel.Processor` instead of a bean, or call your bean from the `Processor` where you write Java code and can call the method directly (not as String name).

Comment: Thanks Claus. This removes my concern. But, with this solution, we need a new processor object every time we need to invoke a bean. Also, the automatic header mapping with @Header annotation on the bean method parameters will not work. We have to programmatically extract the headers from the exchange and pass to the bean method and set the response back in the exchange. I guess there is no other solution other than this?